# spring.data.rest.defaultMediaType=application/json does not work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm trying to set the spring data rest response to be only json and not HATEOS.

I tried placing this rule in application.properties but did not work.
The manual only displays

defaultMediaType - change default media type to use when none is specified

Every other configuration from application.properties is being loaded only this one is not being followed.

```
spring.data.rest.defaultMediaType=application/json
```

Answer (score 0):

This was answered quoting gyoder:
[Optionally disable HATEOAS format in Spring Data Rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070930/optionally-disable-hateoas-format-in-spring-data-rest/27094939#27094939)

The short answer is, you can't use spring-data-rest without hateoas. If you want to build your web service without hateoas, you'll have to write your own controllers (which can still use spring-data repositories).

Quoting Oliver Gierke in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24421538/spring-data-rest-without-hateoas):

> Actually my whole point is: the server is just doing decent REST. If
>   that breaks the client, it's the client that needs to be fixed
>   (tweaked). So the hypermedia aspect is a fundamental one to Spring
>   Data REST and we're not going to back out of that. That's probably not
>   satisfying in your concrete situation but should answer the question
>   at least :). –  Oliver Gierke