# Minimize the size of returned json data from spring data repository

Tags: spring-data-rest

I have two microservice, one of them need at boot to load all operator name/codes and index them in a RadixTree.

I am trying to load around 36000 records using feign/data-rest and it is working but I noticed that in the response approximately half of the data size are coming from links

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "operatorcode" : [ {
      "enabled" : true,
      "code" : 9320,
      "operatorCodeId" : 110695,
      "operatorName" : "Afghanistan - Kabul/9320",
      "operatorId" : 1647,
      "activationDate" : "01-01-2008",
      "deactivationDate" : "31-12-2099",
      "countryId" : 1,
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://10.44.0.51:8083/operatorcode/110695"
        },
        "operatorCode" : {
          "href" : "http://10.44.0.51:8083/operatorcode/110695{?projection}",
          "templated" : true
        },
        "operator" : {
          "href" : "http://10.44.0.51:8083/operatorcode/110695/operator"
        }
      }
    }
...
  ]
}
```

Is there any way to stop sending back the `_links` as in my case it is not being used I tried setting `use-hal-as-default-JSON-media-type: false` and using `projections` but did not succeed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optionally disable HATEOAS format in Spring Data Rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070930/optionally-disable-hateoas-format-in-spring-data-rest)

Comment: i was able to do that manually using `RepositoryRestController`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that it is a correct way to do this but you can try something like this:

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonBuilder() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder b = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    b.mixIn(Object.class, IgnorePropertiesInJackson.class);
    return b;
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties({"_links"})
private abstract class IgnorePropertiesInJackson {
}
```