# How to set the default media type for spring-data-rest?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest, spring-rest

From `RepositoryRestConfiguration` I can see that setting `spring.data.rest.default-media-type=application/json` could change the default media type served by `@RepositoryRestResource`.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class RepositoryRestConfiguration {
    private MediaType defaultMediaType = MediaTypes.HAL_JSON;
}
```

Question: as this class is in `deprecation`, what is the correct way to set/override the default type?

Comment: I can not see deprecation annotation for the complete class, just for some methods: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/config/RepositoryRestConfiguration.html

Comment: In fact even the master branch has the deprecation annotation: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/core/config/RepositoryRestConfiguration.java

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` does not mean that the class is deprecated. There are methods in the class that are annotated with `@Deprecated`. Those are the deprecated methods. The class itself is not deprecated.

Comment: Ah ok, my bad. You're right, `@Deprecated` on class level would make the whole class deprecated, I see.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this via `RepositoryRestConfiguration` or simply with a property in your application.properties. See the documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#getting-started.basic-settings).

The `RepositoryRestConfiguration` class is NOT deprecated. There are methods within it that are deprecated. The `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` annotation on the class does not mean that the class itself is deprecated. That is simply an annotation used to tell an IDE to not display deprecation warnings in the IDE.

The easiest way to do this would be in application.properties. However, you have the property name wrong. You wouldn't set it as `spring.data.rest.default-media-type`. The actual property it would expect is `spring.data.rest.defaultMediaType`. So in your application.properties, you could have:

```
spring.data.rest.defaultMediaType=application/json
```

With the `RepositoryRestConfiguration`, you could accomplish the same as such:

```
@Configuration
class CustomRestMvcConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public RepositoryRestConfigurer repositoryRestConfigurer() {

    return new RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter() {

      @Override
      public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.setDefaultMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the property would be spring.data.rest.defaultMediaType and not spring.data.rest.default-media-type? I'm confused as to why this link shows the latter: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.data.spring.data.rest.default-media-type

Comment: `defaultMediaType` and `default-media-type` should both work thanks to [Relaxed Binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding), but `kebab-case` is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

```java
@Component
public class CustomRestConfig implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void 
    configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.setDefaultMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please avoid writing code only answers. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers