# Spring Boot JPA REST pattern

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Boot to build a REST service. And this works perfectly.

I create a `@Controller`, a `@Service` and a `@Repository` (JpaRepository) layer and a `@Entity` domain class. So I have for example

- Organisation**Controller**
- Organisation**Service**
- Organisation**Repository** and
- Organisation *(domain pojo)*

With a few injections and configs I have my REST API `GET /organisation/1` running. Nice!

But now, after using this strategy extensively I have the feeling this can be done more efficient. And probably Spring (Boot) has thought about this already.

I have worked with a good solution: **HATEOAS** (and HAL). However, I don't really like the complex hateoas json. I would like simple responses (without all the links, embeds and more). What is the best approach to accomplish this?

HATEOAS is pretty much what I need (just simple CRUD operations). I only need more control over the output.

*btw: I prefer Java Config and annotations over XML.*

Comment: Have you looked at http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/ ?

Comment: @reto I just have. Seems like hateoas to me. I get the same response (having links, embeds and all).

Comment: I guess this answers my question about leaving out the Hateoas elements: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24421538/spring-data-rest-without-hateoas