# Remove "_embedded" and "_links" from Spring Boot JSON Response

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I've created a basic Spring Boot application with Restful services using `CrudRepository` to interact with the DB.

The JSON response contains `"_embedded" : { ... }` and `"_links" : { ... }` which I don't want.

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "countries" : [
      {
        "name" : "Antarctica",
        "_links" : {
          "self" : {
            "href" : "http://localhost:8080/world/rest/countries/ATA"
          },
          "country" : {
            "href" : "http://localhost:8080/world/rest/countries/ATA"
          }
        }
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
```

How can I get rid of this structure and return my objects in a simple list?
Is there some property or configuration that can be set to remove this from all responses?

I've added the property `spring.hateoas.use-hal-as-default-json-media-type=false`, didn't work.

Tried converting the result to a list manually, `countries.forEach(countriesList::add);`; no luck..

POJO Class to map objects

```
/* Package and Imports */

@Entity(name = "country")
public class Country {

    @Id
    private String code;

    private String name;
    private String continent;
    private String region;

    /* Getters, Setters and equals method below */
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264044/disable-hypertext-application-language-hal-in-json/53750814#53750814

Comment: @michalk I did have a look at it. Is there no other simple way to do it? A configuration or annotation?

Comment: can you show the corresponding POJO

Comment: @Deadpool updated the question with the POJO

Comment: @LearningDeveloper, try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24421538/spring-data-rest-without-hateoas

Comment: @BorLaze Thanks for the link, the `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` seems to be the culprit. I might need to remove it and implement custom endpoints. Will keep this topic updated.

Answer (score 4):

After going through many topics on StackOverflow and other sites. I've come to the conclusion that I'm better off without the `spring-boot-starter-data-rest`.

1. I've removed the `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` dependency from my `pom.xml`.
2. Created a `@RestController` to handle requests.
3. Created methods to handle different request types (GET, POST, etc.)

---

As suggested by @michalk

[Disable Hypertext Application Language (HAL) in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264044/disable-hypertext-application-language-hal-in-json/53750814#53750814)

This does help partially but not for arrays.